# Erro na busca do select

Tags: android, select, sql-select, crud

Nao to conseguindo retornar o valor dentro do meu arry sempre volta 0

Read

```
   public class Read {
               public ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> getLista() {
         SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Maindb.TABELA;
    ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            RespostasAguaCasa resp = new RespostasAguaCasa();

            resp.setId(c.getInt(1));
            resp.setValoragua(c.getInt(2));
            resp.setAcordarhora(c.getInt(3));
            resp.setAcordarminu(c.getInt(4));
            resp.setDormirhora(c.getInt(5));
            resp.setDormirminu(c.getInt(6));

            lista.add(resp);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        {
        }


    }
    c.close();
    return lista;
}
```

Update

```
public class Update {
SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase dbb = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase dbbb = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
public boolean addResposta(RespostasAguaCasa respostasAguaCasa){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("id" , respostasAguaCasa.getId());
    cv.put("valoragua" , respostasAguaCasa.getValoragua());
    cv.put("acordarhora" , respostasAguaCasa.getAcordarhora());
    cv.put("dormirhora" , respostasAguaCasa.getDormirhora());
    cv.put("terceirahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getTerceirahora());
    cv.put("quartahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuartahora());
    cv.put("quintahora" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuintahora());



    cv.put("acordarminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getAcordarminu());
    cv.put("dormirminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getDormirminu());
    cv.put("terceiraminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getTerceiraminu());
    cv.put("quartaminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuartaminu());
    cv.put("quintaminutos" , respostasAguaCasa.getQuintaminu());
    return  db.insert(Maindb.TABELA, null , cv)!= -1;
}
```

Metodos que estou adicionando e buscando

```
     private void adicionarPessoa() {


    RespostasAguaCasa p = new RespostasAguaCasa();

    p.setId(1);
    p.setValoragua(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.valoragua);
    p.setAcordarhora(EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx);
    p.setAcordarminu(EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
    p.setDormirhora(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxx);
    p.setDormirminu(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexx);
    p.setTerceirahora(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxx);
    p.setTerceiraminu(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxx);
    p.setQuartahora(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxx);
    p.setQuartaminu(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxx);
    p.setQuintahora(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxxx);
    p.setQuintaminu(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxxx);
    if (new Update().addResposta(p)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserido com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao inserir pessoa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
 private void verPessoas() {


    ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> pessoas = new Read().getLista();

    for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++) {
        RespostasAguaCasa p = pessoas.get(i);

        Toast.makeText(this, "gg" + p.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}}

Maindb

```
     public class Maindb extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE = "Projeto";
public static final  int VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABELA = "Aguacasa";

private static Maindb instancia;

public static Maindb getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) instancia = new Maindb();
    return instancia;
}


private Maindb() {
    super(Myapp.getContext(), DATABASE, null, VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    instancia = null;
    super.close();
}
```

}

Se necessario alguma outra informaçao so pedir .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta substituir:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
```

por:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = Maindb.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();
```

pelo que vi, tem de susbstituir todas as ocorrencias

avisa se funcionou

Comment: E o mesmo codigo nao ?

Comment: nao, nao é @aleanderrayson, nao existe o método ".getInstancia" nativo, ou voce usa ".getInstance" ou voce reimplementa o método para corresponder ao seu ".getInstancia" que nao existe

Comment: esse intancia vem do meu maindb vou colocar ele na pergunta